# Merge two activerecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two ActiveRecord models of the same class:

- #1: represents the current committed state of the row/model in the db
- #2: one that is potentially updated information for some of the fields of the first.

What I'm looking for is a way to update #1 on a field by field basis if #2 has a non-nil field.   What's the railsy way of doing this?

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197568/how-best-to-merge-two-objects-and-their-associations-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m1 = SomeModel.first()
m2 = SomeModel.first()

m2.some_attribute = "new value"

m2.attributes.each_pair {|k,v| m1.attributes[k] = v unless v.nil?}
```

Comment: ok, that was roughly my implementation -- so there is nothing in rails natively that does something like this.   thanks!

Comment: well if you just want to know what was changed, you can look at m2.changed_attributes, but this will show you the original value.  if you want to reduce the amount of time to process, you could iterate over that hash and only pull the changes that are flagged as changed.  If there is a better way, i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Just an FYI: if you have associations defined on this model, you'll have to merge those as well.